# How to pass an object to a GTK3 callback?

Tags: c, callback, gtk3

I'm trying to pass an object to the callback of a "clicked" event in order to set the text of the target label.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
    int i;
    GtkWidget *target;
} Data;

void change( GtkWidget *widget,
             Data      *data )
{
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(data->target), "it did!");
}

int main( int   argc,
          char* argv[] )
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window, *label, *button;

    Data data;
    data.i = 0;
    data.target = label;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GTKdemo");
    g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    GtkGrid *grid = gtk_grid_new();

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Click here");
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(change), &data);
    gtk_grid_attach(grid, button, 0,0,1,1);

    label = gtk_label_new("this will change");
    gtk_grid_attach(grid, label, 0,1,1,1);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), GTK_WIDGET(grid));

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to set the text of `label` when `button` is clicked.
I tried [gtk callback multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277279/gtk-callback-multiple-arguments) but no dice. Help?

Comment: The program displays the button and label just fine, but crashes when I click the button. Something is going wrong inside `change()`, I just don't know what.

Comment: I'll need to provide additional data through the object later on. So not using objects isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed it by moving `data.target = label` to execute after the `g_signal_connect` of the button.
Perhaps the problem arose from using the pointer address before the object variables were defined.